# How can I change the data type to run the program faster?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I write a genetic algorithm and I represent the population as a list of 50 chromosomes and every chromosome is a number of 20 string bytes. In order to understand I write an example:

```
[['111000110','110000110','011000110','001000110'],
 [''111001010','111110110','111001110','111000100']]
```

The operations with strings are time consuming and I want to find another way to represent the population.Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Numpy arrays. They are faster than the lists in the Python.As you are much concerned with speed, Numpy is probably the best option for you